# Check a php variable contains a SimpleXMLObject

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to check that the $model variable contains an object of type SimpleXMLObject.

```
$model = convertToSimpleXml($fileName, $filePath);
```

This is the end of the convertToSimpleXml method where the object is returned using simplexml_load_file

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_file($path);
return $simpleXml;
```

I've tried checking it as an array or something similar but no luck with that, have looked around for examples but can't find any clear cut answer to the question. Can anyone help?

Comment: how about `instanceof`?

Comment: `var_dump($path)` for us, if its a **url** it doesn't work like that, `$path` should be a string and formatted similar to this: `"<element>Parent<child>Son</child></element>"`

Comment: I didn't include the rest of the code because it would get too big and its a large xml file. The $simpleXml part returns a simplexmlobject I just need a means to check that it is a simplexmlobject or not when it returns for testing purposes

Comment: $path is just the path to the xml file I'm loading from, when I print out the $model variable it prints out the contents of the simplexmlobject, I'll try instanceof to see if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check the class of your `$simpleXml`:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_file($path);
if($simpleXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
  return $simpleXml;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to frz3993 and maxhb for the suggestion instanceof works perfect!